# Apache Camel Rest Route with processors

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and have been struggling to define a Route for a REST endpoint where I intend to take a request, perform some filtering and processing and return a response. Below is my sample code which does not work, what am I doing wrong ?
And are there examples / documentation for me to achieve similar things i.e. respond with failure response codes in case the request failed validation etc.?

```
public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  public static final String DIRECT_HELLO = "direct:hello";

  private final UpperCaseProcessor upperCaseProcessor;

  public RestRoute(UpperCaseProcessor upperCaseProcessor) {
    this.upperCaseProcessor = upperCaseProcessor;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    rest("/myapp")
        .get("/hello").param().dataType("string").name("name").endParam().to(DIRECT_HELLO);

    from(DIRECT_HELLO)
        .tracing()
        .filter(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getBody() instanceof String)
        .process(upperCaseProcessor)
        .setHeaders(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be a comprehensive answer to all the questions I had asked in my query (since I am still learning) , there is one particular reason why the above code did not work.

In the above code I was checking for the payload to be of type string on the filter `.filter(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getBody() instanceof String)` whereas Rest Path Query Params are `not included` in the body but in the `headers`. The way to fix the above code is to change the filter line to :

```
.filter(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getHeader("name") instanceof String)
```

In the code example the request was getting filtered out and not getting propagated to the processor. When that happens apache-camel's behaviour is to return `204 No Content` in the response.

My interpretation of the rest routes is that Camel will return the output of whatever route you set and unlike Java `Streams` where you need to be careful to add a terminating operation (like `collect()`) in order to have the stream expression actually evaluate ( since streams is lazy evaluation) , with camel routes no termination operation is needed and the o/p will just be whatever the end of your route defined by you is.

There however seems to be some default behaviour around REST response codes being returned.